# Ask for the sizes of multiple pizzas up front

Tags: python

I am trying to have my code ask for the diameter of each pizza and then output it at the end, I believe I have everything else working I just don't know how to have python ask the diameter for each size pizza and then print out all the data for slices, radius, area, and slice area at the end.

```
try:
user_diameter = float(input("Please enter the diameter of your pizza in inches: "))

if MINIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER <= user_diameter <= MAXIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER:
    
    if user_diameter <= EXTRA_SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
        pizza_slices = EXTRA_SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES
        pizza_radius = user_diameter / 2
        pizza_area = PI * (pizza_radius ** 2)
        pizza_slice_area = pizza_area / pizza_slices

    elif user_diameter <= SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
        pizza_slices = SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES
        pizza_radius = user_diameter / 2
        pizza_area = PI * (pizza_radius ** 2)
        pizza_slice_area = pizza_area / pizza_slices
        

    elif user_diameter <= MEDIUM_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
        pizza_slices = MEDIUM_PIZZA_SLICES
        pizza_radius = user_diameter / 2
        pizza_area = PI * (pizza_radius ** 2)
        pizza_slice_area = pizza_area / pizza_slices

    elif user_diameter <= LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
        pizza_slices = LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES
        pizza_radius = user_diameter / 2
        pizza_area = PI * (pizza_radius ** 2)
        pizza_slice_area = pizza_area / pizza_slices
    else:
        pizza_slices = EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES
        pizza_radius = user_diameter / 2
        pizza_area = PI * (pizza_radius ** 2)
        pizza_slice_area = pizza_area / pizza_slices

    print(f"\nAn extra small pizza needs {EXTRA_SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES} slices, the area of the pizza is {pizza_area} cm and the area of each slice is {pizza_slice_area}")
    print(f"\nA small pizza needs {SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES} slices, the area of the pizza is {pizza_area} cm and the area of each slice is {pizza_slice_area}")
    print(f"\nA Medium pizza needs {MEDIUM_PIZZA_SLICES} slices, the area of the pizza is {pizza_area} cm and the area of each slice is {pizza_slice_area}")
    print(f"\nA Large pizza needs {LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES} slices, the area of the pizza is {pizza_area} cm and the area of each slice is {pizza_slice_area}")
    print(f"\nAn extra large pizza needs {EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES} slices, the area of the pizza is {pizza_area} cm and the area of each slice is {pizza_slice_area}")
```

Comment: Am I missing sometjhing? `SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT = float(input('What is the diameter of a small pizza'))`

Comment: @Barmar I need a colon after each diameter limit in the if, elif and else statements so that wouldn't work.

Comment: What does it have to do with the `if`? These are variables you set before any of this code.

Comment: @Barmar My variables are user_diameter, pizza_slices, pizza_radius, pizza_area, and pizza_slice_area if that helps

Comment: @Barmar I am very new to coding so I am struggling to understand things

Comment: @JoeySalads Please add an example of 1) What information you expect the *user* to provide. 2) What you expect your *output* to be given that information.

Comment: @BeRT2me Write a program that will:
• Receive a diameter (float) of a pizza from user.
• Validate the input (try except, if).
• If input is invalid, tell the user (string) and end the program.
• Determine the number of slices for a pizza (int) of that diameter
according to the given decision structure (if…elif…else).
• Calculate the area (float) of the pizza.
• Calculate the area of a slice (float) of that pizza.
• Output the required information (string) in the given format.
• Prompt the user to end the program.

Comment: @BeRT2me that is what I am supposed to do sorry for not giving this info out earlier. I haven't used this website before.

Comment: Add all that, nicely formatted, to the Body of your question via an edit. Then specify exactly where you're stuck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you ask for the size of the requested pizza, ask for all the limits and assign those variables.

```
EXTRA_SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT = float(input("What is the diameter of extra small pizzas? "))
EXTRA_SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES = int(input("How many slices in extra small pizzas? "))
SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT = float(input("What is the diameter of small pizzas? "))
SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES = int(input("How many slices in small pizzas? "))
```

and so on for all the other sizes.